# WCF with self-signed SSL in IIS 6.0, getting strange error on client

Tags: wcf, configuration, ssl

I have a WCF service that is running on IIS 6, and must be accessed via SSL, containing a self-signed certificate. I've gone through the configuration a million times and everything look correct, but I'm getting the following error from my client app:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
>
> EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at https://207.136.158.108/vca_mp/MarketingDataServices.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action

The address is correct, I'm guessing it's something to do with the config. Here's my client config:

```
<bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IMarketingDataServices" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000000" messageEncoding="Text">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://207.136.158.108/vca_mp/MarketingDataServices.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IMarketingDataServices"
            contract="MarketingDataServicesReference.IMarketingDataServices"
            name="WSHttpBinding_IMarketingDataServices">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
```

Any help someone can provide would be soooooo appreciated.

Best,
Sebastian G.
sgvirtzman@directpartners.com

Comment: Could you show the service configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the service configuration:

```
<behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="IMPIntranet.WebServices.MarketingDataServicesBehavior">
     <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>




<services>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="IMPIntranet.WebServices.MarketingDataServicesBehavior"
    name="IMPIntranet.WebServices.MarketingDataServices">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IMPIntranet.WebServices.IMarketingDataServices">
     <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
     </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
   </service>
  </services>
```

Answer (score 0):

Self signed certs do not work well with WCF as they don't provide a certificate revocation list, or a trusted root certificate. You can use makecert to create a root certificate, CRL and subsequent certificates by following [the instructions on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949011.aspx)